# Сделать кликабельным (при клике) пункт меню с вложенным (выпадающим) меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Имеется меню для мобильной версии, которое содержит выпадающую ссылку "Услуги". Проблема в том, что для того, чтобы подменю выпало, нужно нажать на стрелку, которая находится справа от пункта "Услуги". Как сделать так, чтобы можно было открыть подменю не при нажатии на стрелку, а при нажатии на всю ссылку "Услуги", которая находится в теге li.

Прилагаю ссылку на CodePen. Спасибо.

html:

```
<header class="header">
   <div class="container-header">
      <div class="header__top">
         <div class="header__content">
            <div class="select-web">
               <button><img src="../img/header/top_arrow.svg" alt="arrow"></button>
               <span>Хирургический центр</span>
            </div>
            <div class="working__mode">
               <p>Ежедневно 9:00-20:00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="address__and__schedule">
               <a href="#" class="link__address">Адрес и график работы</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="hr__header">

      <div class="header__middle">
         <div class="header__content">
            <div class="logo__block">
               <a href="../index.php"><img src="../img/header/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="search__block">
               <form action="#" method="POST" class="form__search">
                  <a href="#"><img src="../img/icons/search.svg" class="img-search" alt="search"></a>
                  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Поиск">
               </form>
            </div>
            <div class="phone__block">
               <a href="#">891236182</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="hr__header">
      <div class="main__menu">
         <div class="header__menu">
            <div class="header__burger">
               <span></span>
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
            <div class="logo__media__version">
               <a href="../index.php"><img src="../img/header/logo-mobile.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="phone__header">
               <a href="tel:+73466290028"><img src="../img/icons/phone.png" alt="phone"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="search__media__version">
               <a href="#"><img src="../img/icons/search-header-media-version.png" alt="search"></a>
            </div>
            <nav class="menu">
               <ul class="menu__list">
                  <li><a href="../index.php" class="menu__link">Главная</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu__link">О компании</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu__link">Сотрудники</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <!-- <input type="checkbox" id="menu" name="toggle" class="toggleSubMenu" id="sub-m1"> -->
                     <a href="" class="menu__link">Услуги</a>
                     <!-- <label for="menu" class="toggleMenu"></label> -->
                     <span class="menu__arrow arrow"></span>
                     <ul class="sub-menu__list">
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Выпадающая ссылка 1</a>
                           <span class="sub-menu__arrow arrow"></span>
                           <ul class="sub-sub-menu__list">
                              <li><a href="#" class="sub-sub-menu__link">Testing System</a>
                              </li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Выпадающая ссылка 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Выпадающая ссылка 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sub-menu__link">Выпадающая ссылка 4</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu__link">Цены</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu__link">Отзывы</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../pages/contacts.php" class="menu__link">Контакты</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

css:

```
* {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   border: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

:focus,
:active {
   outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
   outline: none;
}

nav,
footer,
header,
aside {
   display: block;
}

html,
body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 100%;
   line-height: 1;
   font-size: 14px;
   -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
   -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
   font-family: inherit;
}

input::-ms-clear {
   display: none;
}

button {
   cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}

a,
a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
   list-style: none;
}

img {
   vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
   font-size: inherit;
   font-weight: 300;
}


.container-header {
   max-width: 1440px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
   background-color: #fff;
   box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   font-family: 'KievitMedium';
}

.hr__header {
   width: 100%;
   border: 0.017em solid #dbdbdb;
}

.menu [type="checkbox"],
.menu label {
   display: none;
}

.menu label.toggleSubMenu {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
}

.phone__header {
   display: none;
}

.header__content {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   height: 114px;
}

.header__top {
   height: 60px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

button {
   background-color: initial;
}

.select-web {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.select-web button {
   height: 10px;
}

.select-web span {
   margin-left: 7px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border-bottom: 1px dashed #EF7F1A;
   color: #333;
}

.working__mode {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: 8.5%;
}

.working__mode {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.working__mode p {
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #333;
   font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
}

.address__and__schedule {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.address__and__schedule a {
   font-size: 18px;
   color: #702C23;
   border-bottom: 1px dashed #EF7F1A;
}

/* header middle */

.search__block {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: 6.5%;
}

.search__block,
.logo__block {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.search__block input {
   font-size: 17px;
   color: #333333;
   width: 300px;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   margin-left: 15px;
   padding-left: 10px;
}

.search__block input::placeholder {
   font-size: 17px;
   color: #333333;
}

.img-search {
   width: 23px;
   height: 23px;
}

.form__search {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.phone__block a {
   color: #000;
   font-size: 26px;
   font-family: 'KievitBold';
   font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
}

.header__menu {
   height: 65px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
   font-family: 'KievitRegular';
}

.menu li {
   position: relative;
}

.menu__list {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.menu__list>li+li {
   margin-left: 25px;
}

.menu a.parent {
   margin: 0px 25px 0px 0px;
}

.menu__list li a {
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #0A0A0A;
}

.menu__list li a:hover {
   color: #EF7F1A;
}

.sub-menu__list {
   display: none;
   font-family: 'KievitRegular';
   position: absolute;
   min-width: 320px;
   z-index: 9999;
   left: 0;
   top: 15px;
   padding: 27px 0px;
}

.sub-menu__list>li {
   background-color: #fefefe;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}


.sub-menu__link {
   color: #0a0a0a;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 15px 20px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
   font-size: 18px;
   transition: 0.2s;
}

.sub-sub-menu__list {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 100%;
   min-width: 320px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
}

.sub-sub-menu__list>li {
   background-color: #fefefe;
}

.sub-sub-menu__link {
   color: #0a0a0a;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 15px 20px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
   font-size: 18px;
   transition: 0.2s;
}

.sub-menu__list li a {
   display: block;
}

.arrow {
   
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 5px;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 8px solid #0A0A0A;
   border-right: 8px solid transparent;
   border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

.arrow.active {
   transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
   top: 17px;
   right: 10px;
   border-left: 8px solid #0A0A0A;
   border-right: none;
   border-top: 8px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;

}

body.mouse .menu__list>li:hover .sub-menu__list {
   display: block;
}

body.mouse .sub-menu__list>li:hover .sub-sub-menu__list {
   display: block;
}



.header__burger,
.search__media__version,
.logo__media__version {
   display: none;
}

/* media */

@media screen and (max-width: 10000px) {


   .header__middle,
   .header__top,
   .hr__header {
      display: none;
   }

   .header {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
   }

   .header:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #fefefe;
      z-index: 3;
   }

   .header__burger {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      width: 30px;
      height: 20px;
      z-index: 3;
   }

   .header__menu {
      height: 60px;
      justify-content: space-between;
   }

   .header__burger:before,
   .header__burger:after {
      content: '';
      background-color: #757575;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      left: 0;
      transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
   }

   .header__burger span {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #757575;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      top: 9px;
      transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
   }

   .header__burger:before {
      top: 0;
   }

   .header__burger:after {
      bottom: 0;
   }

   .menu {
      position: fixed;
      top: -100%;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #e42945;
      padding: 70px 0px 0px 0px;
      transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
      overflow: auto;
   }

   .menu.active {
      top: 0;
   }

   .menu__list {
      display: block;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
   }

   .menu__list li a {
      display: block;
      color: #fff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .1);
      padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
   }

   .sub-menu__list {
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      position: initial;
   }

   .sub-menu__list.open {
      text-transform: none;
   }

   .sub-menu__list.open li a {
      color: #0A0A0A;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
   }

   .menu__list li a:hover {
      color: #fff;
   }

   .sub-menu__list.open li a:hover {
      color: #0A0A0A;
   }

   /* .menu a.parent {
      margin: 0;
   } */

   .menu__list>li+li {
      margin-left: 0;
   }

   .sub-menu__list li {
      padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
   }


   .sub-menu__list li:last-child {
      padding-bottom: 10px;
   }

   .menu__list>li {
      margin: 10px 0px 20px 0px;
   }

   .header__burger.active span {
      transform: scale(0);
   }

   .header__burger.active:before {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      top: 9px;
   }

   .header__burger.active:after {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      bottom: 9px;
   }

   .main-slider {
      margin-top: 68px;
   }

   .phone__header,
   .search__media__version,
   .logo__media__version {
      display: block;
      z-index: 3;
   }

   .logo__media__version img {
      height: 55px;
   }

   .arrow {
      border-top: 8px solid #fff;
      right: 40%;
   }

   .sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
      top: 7px;
   }

   .sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
      top: 19px;
      right: 35%;
   }

   .sub-sub-menu__list {
      position: inherit;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
   }

   .sub-sub-menu__list>li {
      background-color: #fff;
   }
  
  .sub-menu__list.open {display: block;}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   .arrow {
      right: 38%;
   }

   .sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
      right: 32%;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 670px) {
   .arrow {
      right: 37%;
   }

   .sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
      right: 29%;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
   .arrow {
      right: 35%;
   }

   .sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
      right: 26%;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .arrow {
      right: 33%;
   }

   .sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
      right: 23%;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
   .arrow {
      right: 31%;
   }

   .sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
      right: 20%;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   .arrow {
      right: 28%;
   }

   .sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
      right: 17%;
   }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 365px) {
   .arrow {
      right: 25%;
   }

   .sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
      right: 14%;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {

   .sub-menu__arrow.arrow {
      right: 9%;
   }
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.header__burger').click(function (event) {
      $('.header__burger, .header__menu, .menu').toggleClass('active');
      $('body').toggleClass('lock');
   });
});




let body = document.querySelector('body');


   body.classList.add('touch');
   let arrow = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');

   for (i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
      let thisLink = arrow[i].previousElementSibling;
      let subMenu = arrow[i].nextElementSibling;
      let thisArrow = arrow[i];

      thisLink.classList.add('parent');
      arrow[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
         subMenu.classList.toggle('open');
         thisArrow.classList.toggle('active');
      });
   }

https://codepen.io/Vladislav_Biryukov/pen/oNEpRzZ
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этой строчке

```
arrow[i].addEventListener('click', ...)
```

необходимо поменять `arrow[i]` на `thisLink`.
Чтобы событие по клику назначалось на ссылку.

И добавьте `#` в `href` ссылки

```
<a href="#" class="menu__link">Услуги</a>
```